# View not loading up in iOS simulator for xCode

Tags: ios, swift, view, sprite-kit, ios-simulator

My problem is that whenever I try to load up the code I have below, a blank grey screen pops up with none of my sprites on it. There are no errors yet nothing will happen in the simulator.

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    /* Setup your scene here */
    backgroundColor = SKColor.brownColor()
    let start = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Chalkduster")
    start.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width/4, y: self.frame.size.height/2)
    start.text = "start"
    start.color = SKColor.blackColor()  
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
   /* Called when a touch begins */

       }

override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
}
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the label to the view? (`addSubview`)

Comment: With this code you should see only a brown background, if you are not seeing this, you should check if the GameViewController is instantiating the GameScene. ( check the code with a new project and see if it checks out)

Comment: UlyssesR, the GameViewController is initiating the GameScene and I added it to the view and the text did not come up either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 things to solve this.

1. Add the node to the scene.

You have to call,

```
    self.addChild(start)
```

To actually add the node in the Scene.

2. The location.

This is not in the visible area of the screen

```
CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width/4, y: self.frame.size.height/2)
```

Try this code out.

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    /* Setup your scene here */
    backgroundColor = SKColor.brownColor()
    let start = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Chalkduster")
    start.text = "start"
    start.position = CGPoint(x: (self.scene?.size.width)!/2, y: (self.scene?.size.height)!/2)
    start.color = SKColor.blackColor()

    self.addChild(start)        


}
```